# Customising the XML formatter in Eclipse?

Tags: xml, eclipse

How do I customise the XML formatter in Eclipse? I've looked inside the preferences menu in the XML node but can't find it there. Am I just missing it or is it hidden elsewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `format` in the quick search field above the TreeView in the eclipse preferences and the preferences will be reduced to show only format preferences. You find then easily

```
XML -> XML Files -> Editor
```

Here you can configure some few settings.