# How to customize Android XML formatter settings in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, customization, adt, eclipse-adt, xml-formatting

This question is an extension of previous posts such as:

- [Customising the XML formatter in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356496/customising-the-xml-formatter-in-eclipse)
- [How to configure Eclipse XML formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943350/how-to-configure-eclipse-xml-formatting)

I would like to customize the settings which are used to format XML files in Android projects. I found the following basic option in the preferences of Eclipse IDE.

> Eclipse format XML using the standard Android XML style rather than the configured Eclipse XML style.

[image: Eclipse IDE Preferences / Android / Editors]

I want **every XML file to end with a line break** but I cannot configure this here.

Eclipse IDE allows to configure this setting for Java files. The option "New Lines ... at end of file" can be enabled in `Eclipse IDE Preferences / Java / Code Style / Formatter` as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Eclipse IDE Preferences / Java / Code Style / Formatter]

It would be great if there is a **configuration file** such as for Java settings which can be exchanged by members of a team and put under version control.

Comment: I am also interested in how to do this. When I auto format XML files and add them to a Git repo I get those pesky "\ No newline at end of file" warnings on Git command line and the red warning symbols on GitHub.